# Jquery mobile select control within listview not refreshing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am dynamically appending list items to a listview.
Within each listview item I have a couple of

text

fields and a select control.
I refresh the listview after appending and everything styles correctly except for the select controls. They are not being included as part of the listview refresh.
I have tried a .create() method on the content div. Nothing is working.
I believe somehow I need to refresh the list and all the multiple selects on the page
but not sure how.

Comment: try $('#pageId').trigger('create');

Answer (score 0):

You may have to update the `buttongroup` or `controlgroup` as well and use `updatelayout`.

Comment: I had to do a listView refresh before the $('#pageId').trigger('create'); in order to get it to style the list and selects. Thanks

Comment: I am not using buttongroups or controlgroups. We are creating a web app that can go offline. We are reading data from a local db. On this page I have to show from 1 to 99+ line items that allow someone the change the status of a line item. It would be hard to show all the code.